# target all element except one (jquery)

Tags: jquery, selector

I need some help for a little jquery selector...

I need to call a function on keypress action, but I need to call this function only when the user isn't in a `<form>`.

I try with `$('body').not('form').keypress(getKey)` but it doesn't work

I tried with some combinaison of `.not()` selector but I didn't do nothing well...

So if someone had an idea how I can do it...

Thanks you

Comment: What do you mean by "in a?"

Comment: Probably means that a form field doesn't have the focus.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(document).on('keypress', function (e) {
    if (!$(e.target).closest('form').length) {
       //not in a form
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/ZfAdk/

Comment: You are missing `length` property.

Comment: @undefined a second too late

Comment: @Promo `$("body").not('form')` selects all elements that are not forms including children of the form

Answer (score 0):

```
$('*:not(form *)').bind('keypress', function (e) {
       // not in a form
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zmc2z/

Comment: It doesn't run. The first solution was the best ;)